# What is the real use of logical addresses?

Tags: operating-system, computer-science, memory-address

This is what I understood of logical addresses :

Logical addresses are used so that data on the physical memory do not get corrupted. By the use of logical addresses, the processes wont be able to access the physical memory directly, thereby ensuring that it cannot store data on already accessed physical memory locations and hence protecting data integrity.
I have a doubt whether it was really necessary to use logical addresses. The integrity of the data on the physical memory could have been preserved by using an algorithm or such which do not allow processes to access or modify memory locations which were already accessed by other processes.

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. (Append two blank spaces to a line you want a break after.) You are right in *memory protection* and *address translation* being independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The integrity of the data on the physical memory could have been preserved by using an algorithm or such which do not allow processes to access or modify memory locations which were already accessed by other processes."

**Short Answer: It is impossible to devise an efficient algorithm as proposed to match the same level of performance with logical address.**

The issue with this algorithm is that how are you going to intercept each processes' memory access? Without intercepting memory access, it is impossible to check if a process has privileges to access certain memory region. If we are really going to implement this algorithms, there are ways to intercept memory access without using the logical address provided by MMU (Memory management unit) on modern cpus (Assume you have a cpu without MMU). However, those methods will not be as efficient as using MMU. If your cpu does have a MMU, although logical address translation will be unavoidable, you could setup a one-to-one to the physical memory.

One way to intercept memory access without MMU is to insert kernel trap instruction before each memory access instruction in a program. Since we cannot trust user level program, such job cannot be delegated to a compiler. Thus, you can write an OS which will do this job before it loads a program into memory. This OS will scan through the binary of your program and insert kernel trap instruction before each memory access. By doing so, kernel can inspect if a memory access should be granted. However, this approach downgrades your system's performance a lot as each memory access, legal or not, will trap into the kernel. And trapping into kernel involves context switching which takes a lot of cpu cycles.

Can we do better? What about do a static analysis of memory access of our programs before we load it into memory so we only insert trap before illegal memory access?  However, processes has no predefined execution order. Let's say you have programs A and B. They both try to access the same memory region. Then who should get it with our static analysis? We could randomly assign to one of them. Let's say we assign to B. Then how do we know when will B be done with this memory so we can give to A so it can proceed? Let's say B use this region to hold a global variable, which accessed multiple times throughout its life cycle. Do we wait till the completion of B to give this region to A? What if B never ends?

Furthermore, a static analysis of memory access would be impossible with the present of dynamic memory allocation. If either program A or B tries to allocate a memory region which size depends on user input, then OS or our static analysis tool cannot know ahead of time of where or how big the region is. And thus would not be able to do analysis at all.

Thus, we have to fall back to trap on every memory access and determine if access is legal on runtime. Sounds familiar? This is the function of MMU or logical address. However, with logical address, a trap is incurred if and only if a illegal access has happened instead of every memory access.

Answer (score 0):

It is simulated by the OS to programs as if they were using physical memory. The need of the extra layer (logical address) is necessary for data-integrity purposes. You can make the analogy of logical addresses as the language of OS for addresses because without this **Mapping**, OS would not be able to understand what are the "actual" addresses allowed to any program. To remove this ambiguity, logical address mapping is required so that the OS know what logical address maps to what physical addressing and whether that physical address location is allowed to that program. It performs the "integrity checks" on logical addresses and not on physical memory because you can check the integrity by changing the logical address and do manipulations but you cant really do the same on physical memory because it would affect the already running processes using the memory.

Also I would like to mention that the base register and limit register are loaded by executing privileged instructions and privileged instructions are executed in kernel mode and only operating system has access to kernel mode and therefore CPU cannot directly access the registers. I hope I helped a little :)

Answer (score 0):

There are some things that you need to understand.

First of all a CPU is unable to access the physical memory directly. In order to calculate the physical address a CPU needs a logical address. Logical address is then used compute the physical address. So this is the basic need of logical addresses to access physical memory. Without logical address you cannot access it. This conversion is necessary. Suppose if there is a system which do not follow virtual/logical addresses, that system will become highly vulnerable to hacker or intruder as they can access physical memory directly and manipulate the useful data on any location.

Second thing, when a process runs, CPU generates logical address in order to load that process on main memory. Now the purpose of this logical address here is, the memory management. The size of registers are very less as compared to the actual size of process. So we need to relocate the memory in order to obtain the optimum efficiency. MMU (Memory Management Unit) comes into play here. Physical memory is calculated by MMU using the logical address. So logical addresses are generated by processes and MMU access physical address based on that logical address.

This example will make it clear.

If data is stored on address 50, base register holds the value 50 and offset holds 0. Now, MMU shifts it to address 100, this would be reflected in logical address as well. Offset becomes 100-50=50. So, now if data is needed to be retrieved via logical address, it goes to base address 50 and then see the offset i.e. 50, it goes to address 100 and access data. Logical address keeps the record of the data where it has been moved. No matter how many address locations that data change, it will be reflected in logical address and hence this  logical address give accessibility to that data whatever physical address it holds now.

I hope it helps.